# HTML - jQuery blur( function() is triggered on entry and then loops

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to validate two telephone numbers. The first telephone number validation works fine; however, if the first telephone number is invalid and I then go the the second telephone number then the second telephone number validation is triggered, before I have entered any data, and I have a loop "Invalid phone number 1c" until I close the tab.

For instance I enter "99999999" in the first telephone number then tab. The message "Please use Area Code for landline numbers" is displayed and then a continuous loop of "Invalid phone number 1c" is displayed.

If I enter an invalid telephone number and then go to another field, other than the second telephone number, I just get an error message once (e.g., enter "99999999" in the first telephone number then click on another text entry field, e.g., State).

```js
$("#telephone1").blur(function() {
  validatePhoneNumber($(this).val(), this.id);
});

$("#telephone2").blur(function() {
  validatePhoneNumber($(this).val(), this.id);
});

function validatePhoneNumber(phone_number, id) {
  var formatted = "";
  //remove all non-digits
  phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\D/g, '');
  //if number starts with 61, replace 61 with 0
  if (phone_number.match(/^61/)) {
    phone_number = "0" + phone_number.slice(2);
  }

  if (phone_number.match(/^04/)) {
    if (phone_number.length === 10) {
      var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g, "$1 $2 $3");
    } else {
      alert('Invalid phone number 1a');
    }
  } else if (phone_number.match(/^02|03|07|08/)) {
    if (phone_number.length === 10) {
      var formatted = phone_number.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g, "($1) $2 $3");
    } else {
      alert('Invalid phone number 1b');
    }
  } else if (phone_number.length === 8) {
    alert('Please use Area Code for landline numbers');
  } else {
    alert('Invalid phone number 1c');
  }
  //update
  $('#' + id).val(formatted);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="telephone1" class="text-right col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-form-label">Telephone:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" id="telephone1" name="telephone1" placeholder="Telephone 1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="telephone2" class="text-right col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-form-label"></label>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" id="telephone2" name="telephone2" placeholder="Telephone 2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `change` instead of `blur`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a combination of using `alert` for your error messages, using `onblur` for your validation and tabbing between elements. I would suggest using `onchange` instead or having the function exit if there is no value entered at all. Then you won't be getting spammed with alerts. Additionally, the `blur` event can get called for several different reasons, as they mention in their docs, whereas `change` checks for a change in value when the element loses focus